# error in .htaccess file

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have written this .htacces file for my upcoming web portal

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^about-us about-us.php
RewriteRule ^blog blog.php

ErrorDocument 400 /errors/badrequest.html

RewriteRule ^blogs/([^/\.]+)/?$ post.php?blogname=$1 [L,NC,QSA]

RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ single.php?username=$1
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/$ single.php?username=$1
```

from above if my url is http://localhost/makin/single.php?username=ankit
 it converts it into  http://localhost/makin/ankit that is what i want.

But when i am changing url like **localhost/makin/shdfhdhghhdsj** it shows the same page instead the username is not correct .or if put any thing like **localhost/makin/ankit***shfhjshdfjh*  after username anything it shows same page like  what i want is to show the error if someone try to open with fake username.. Please help me out guys with this

Comment: I think you need to use PHP to determine if the user name is valid or not

Comment: but i am not using any session variable..can't it be done with .htaccess file it should written error page

Comment: You only need to check if the username is valid, no need for sessions.

Comment: and how i can prevent it if someone put  / after username for eg: http://localhost/makin/ankit/ it shows same page ....how can i remove this /

Comment: guys can anyone help me with this error : if i am using this url http://localhost/makin/about-us/sdssdfd and i have written this rule ( RewriteRule ^about-us about-us.php ) it still shows the same about-us page how can i remove this error...

Answer (score 1):

Inside your file single.php, check if the value of $_Get["username"] is valid or not. If it is not valid, do a redirect to an "invalid" username "page" else load single.php as usual

Comment: and how i can prevent it if someone put  / after username for eg: http://localhost/makin/ankit/ it shows same page ....how can i remove this /

Comment: You don't need to remove the extra "/" at the end. mod_rewrite or rewrites threats the clean URL as a form of a folder. If you need to remove the extra "/" that they will put, you either need to write a new rule that removes the extra "/" at the end or parse it out yourself by checking if the last char is a "/" and replace it with nothing.

Comment: @Ankitsingh You can not impliment this from .htaccess, as the first commenter says "you need php script and a mysql query to check if a username exists or not.

Comment: @Ankitsingh Remove the last RewriteRule

Comment: @Starkeen one last thing : if i am using this url http://localhost/makin/about-us/sdssdfd and i have written this rule ( RewriteRule ^about-us about-us.php  )   it still shows the same about-us page how can i remove this error...